# What is the value of second after executing the following lines? in python

Tags: python

What is the value of second after executing the following lines?

```
first = "wombat"
second = ""
for i in range(len(first),0,-1):
    second = first[i-1] + second
```

why the answer is not '`tabmow`' i.e reverse of the string `first`

Comment: Because you *prefix* `second` with each character from `first`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping through the letters in reverse order, which is the right idea. However, you prepend the letters into `second` one by one, meaning, the first letter you visit becomes the last letter of `second`. So, you're looping in reverse order, but constructing in reverse order as well.

Try this:

```
for i in range(len(first),0,-1):
    second = second + first[i-1]
```

Comment: thanks , i got it , looping in reverse and constructing too in reverse

Answer (score 0):

Your code ends with second being equal to "wombat".  You have the order of `second = first[i-1] + second` reversed.  It should be `second = second + first[i-1]`

Comment: how wombat i need to ask , because if we put the values mine answer comes reverse of wombat can you please elaborate